# Excel VBA - always show worksheet on open

Tags: excel, vba

How can the following conditions be met with VBA code?

1. A particular worksheet is always displayed on open, even if the worbook is opened without enabling macros.
2. A workbook user may save the workbook while working on any worksheet.
3. The save must not interfere with the user - no navigating away to a different sheet, no messageboxes, etc.
4. The regular save functions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, clicking Save) must remain available and when used must obey the criteria above.

I'd like to avoid the attempted solutions I've listed at the bottom of this question.

**Details:**
The workbook is created using Office 2007 on a Windows 7 machine. It is an .xlsm workbook with 2 worksheets, "Scheduler" and "Info." Sheet tabs are not visible. Not all users will enabled macros when the workbook is opened.

Upon opening the workbook, a user will only be exposed to one sheet as follows:

- "Info" shows up if macros are disabled, and basically tells anyone who opens the workbook that macros need to be enabled for full workbook functionality. If macros are enabled at this point, "Scheduler" is activated.
- "Scheduler" is where data is stored and edited, and is automatically shown if macros are enabled. It is not presented to the user when the workbook is opened without macros enabled.

"Info" must show up first thing if the workbook is opened and macros are disabled.

**Attempted Solutions** (I'm looking for better solutions!):

- *Placing code in the `Workbook.BeforeSave` event.* This saves with "Info" activated so it shows up when the workbook is opened. However, if the user is in "Scheduler" and not done, I cannot find a way in this event to re-activate "Scheduler" after the save.
- *Using `Application.OnKey` to remap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> keystrokes.* Unfortunately this leaves out the user who saves using the mouse (clicking File...Save or Office Button...Save).
- *Checking during every action and if needed activating "Scheduler".* In other words, inserting code in something like the `Workbook.SheetActivate` or `.SheetChange` events to put "Scheduler" back into focus after a save with "Info" activated. This runs VBA code constantly and strikes me as a good way to get the other code in the workbook into trouble.
- *Placing code in the `Worksheet("Info").Activate` event*, to change focus back to "Scheduler". This leads to the result of "Scheduler", not "Info", showing when the workbook is opened, even with macros disabled.

Comment: `"Info" must show up first thing if the workbook is opened and macros are disabled.` If macros are disabled then why try the `Attempted Solutions` :) or am I missing something here?

Comment: Good question - the workbook contains macros, but is opened on a shared drive by users that may or may not have the location in their trusted file paths. So, for those who will open without the macros enabled, I use the "Info" sheet to say, "turn on the macros!" Once they are turned on, then I need to make sure that, no matter what is changed on the workbook, once it is saved the next person who opens up the workbook with macros disabled sees "Info".

Comment: The only way I can think of is to save the file in readonly mode. That ways it will always open with info sheet as the first sheet... provided you save and close the file with info sheet active. Excel remembers the last sheet that you opened.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option, as others need to modify "Scheduler", and the workbook needs to save these modifications :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have time to test this out, but you might be able to do this using `Application.OnTime` in your BeforeSave event handler.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objActiveSheet
    Set objActiveSheet = Me.ActiveSheet
    If objActiveSheet Is InfoSheet Then Exit Sub
    If Module1.PreviousSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set Module1.PreviousSheet = objActiveSheet
        InfoSheet.Activate
        Application.OnTime Now, "ActivatePreviousSheet"
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in Module1:

```
Public PreviousSheet As Worksheet

Public Sub ActivatePreviousSheet()
    If Not PreviousSheet Is Nothing Then
        PreviousSheet.Activate
        Set PreviousSheet = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what this code does, but I'm confused why .OnTime earliest time = Now. Does the actual save happen once the BeforeSave event concludes? And if so, wouldn't .OnTime happen before the save?

Comment: @AaronThomas, OnTime won't happen before the save: VBA is single-threaded, so anything scheduled using Application.OnTime can't run until the current code returns control to the message loop - either by running to completion or by calling DoEvents.  In this case, the file save completes before the scheduled action can run.  In fact, if the file save is being done as the result of closing the workbook, the close will run to completion too, and the scheduled action won't run at all.  All of which is exactly what you want as far as I can see.

Comment: Works well except for one issue - as a side effect of this, if the user tries to close the workbook, then clicks "Yes" to save their work, Application.OnTime executes after the workbook closes. This causing the workbook to re-open and execute sub "PreviousSheet". Any ideas on how to kill this if the user is trying to save when closing the workbook?

Comment: Actually, got that part taken care of. Added a closing_check global, set to true if event Workbook_BeforeClose occurs, and changed Application.OnTime to `If closing_check = False Then Application.OnTime Now, "ActivatePreviousSheet"`. Works great, thank you!

Comment: @AaronThomas - I wasn't aware that scheduling using OnTime would cause the workbook containing the scheduled macro to reopen - hence my remark "...and the scheduled action won't run at all" in my previous comment is wrong.  But it makes sense when you think about it, and your solution sounds good.

Comment: This is the most elegant answer that addresses all the issues I was running into. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Will this not work? **Updated to handle Saving gracefully**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scheduler").Activate
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Activate
    If (ShouldSaveBeforeClose()) Then
        Me.Save
    Else
        Me.Saved = True ' Prevents Excel Save prompt.
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ShouldSaveBeforeClose() As Boolean
    Dim workbookDirty As Boolean
    workbookDirty = (Not Me.Saved)
    If (Not workbookDirty) Then
        ShouldSaveBeforeClose= False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim response As Integer
    response = MsgBox("Save changes to WorkBook?", vbYesNo, "Attention")
    ShouldSaveBeforeClose= (response = VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes)
End Function
```

Comment: I think that's a good option, except in the case where the user may not want to save what they've done! This forces those unwanted changes to be saved anyway. Still +1 for the BeforeClose event, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I updated by answer to handle your valid concern about saving.

Comment: Your update for the saving issue is workable, but starts out overly complex. I'd drop `workbookDirty` and simply check `if (thisworkbook.saved) then` Otherwise essentially you're taking `Not Not Me.Saved` double negatives are best avoided.

Comment: I don't think this meets all criteria. Consider this scenario - the user edits "Scheduler", saves, edits "Scheduler" some more, but decides they do not want to save the most recent edits before closing. The workbook will not open with "Info" activated.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: Here is a re-write that does not utilize AfterSave. You may need to tweak the dialog created from GetSaveAsFilename according to your needs.

This relies on overriding default save behavior and handling the save yourself.

```
Private actSheet As Worksheet
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    PrepareForSave
    manualSave SaveAsUI
    AfterSave ThisWorkbook.Saved
End Sub
Private Sub PrepareForSave()
    Set actSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Activate
    hidesheets
End Sub
Private Sub manualSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo SaveError 'To catch failed save as
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If SaveAsUI Then
        If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
            sPathname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
            If sPathname = False Then 'User hit Cancel
                GoTo CleanUp
            End If
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPathname, FileFormat:=52
        Else
            sPathname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
            If sPathname = False Then
                GoTo CleanUp
            End If
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPathname, FileFormat:=xlNormal
        End If
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
SaveError:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        'Cannot access save location
        'User clicked no to overwrite
        'Or hit cancel
    End If
CleanUp:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub AfterSave(ByVal bSaved As Boolean)
    showsheets
    If actSheet Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scheduler").Activate
    Else
        actSheet.Activate
        Set actSheet = Nothing
    End If
    If bSaved Then
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub hidesheets()
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Info" Then
            ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub showsheets()
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AfterSave True
End Sub
```

The only way to make `Info` display first without macros enabled is if that is how the workbook was saved. This is most reasonably handled when saving.

Unless I misunderstood your issue, not using [BeforeSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840057%28v=office.14%29.aspx) seems misguided. Just make sure to use [AfterSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836466%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as well. Here's an example:

```
Private actSheet As Worksheet
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    showsheets
    actSheet.Activate
    Set actSheet = Nothing
    Thisworkbook.Saved = true 'To prevent save prompt from appearing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set actSheet = ThisWorkbook.activeSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Activate
    hidesheets
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    showsheets
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scheduler").Activate
End Sub
Private Sub hidesheets()
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Info" Then
            ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub showsheets()
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

The use of the private object actSheet allows the "ActiveSheet" to be reselected after save.

Edit: I noticed you had more requirements in the comments. The code has been updated so that now upon saving, only the Info sheet will be visible, but when opened or after saving, every sheet will reappear.

This makes it so that any user opening the file without macros will not be able to save with a different sheet activated, or even view the other sheets. That would certainly help motivate them to enable macros!

Comment: Technically, someone opening the workbook without macros could still add a sheet and save with that sheet selected. If that becomes a problem though, you can Protect Workbook, but then you'll need to include logic for that in your code.

Comment: "...Just make sure to use AfterSave as well" - and make sure all your users are using Office 2010 or later, because that's when the AfterSave event was added.

Comment: @Joe Ah, it makes sense that no one else suggested it then. :) In that case you can [handle it all in the BeforeSave event](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428746-workbook-after-save-event.html) by cancelling the save and handling the save yourself via code. Possibly using `Application.OnTime` like you suggested may work, but I'd hate to have to resort to that.

Comment: Sorry @DanielCook, using Office 2007 unfortunately.

Comment: @DanielCook this looks like it would work, but I think overwriting the entire "save" process seems like a bit too much. The [answer that uses Application.OnTime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19146233/2658159) makes do without changing much of the actual save process.

Comment: You're aboslutely right. The version with Application.OnTime is a quite good use of it. I've just run into some rather ackward complications in using Application.Ontime before, so I wanted to avoid it. Obviously it has it's uses.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been flogged to death in the past, its just hard to find a solution that actually works.   Take a look at this code which should do what you need.  Basically it shows a splash screen, with all other sheets hidden if the user does not enable macros.  It will still save normally if the user clicks save and wont interfere with their work.  If they save with there worksheet open it will still show only the splash screen when next opened.  Download the sample file below and you can test for yourself, make sure you download the file posted by Reafidy it has over 400 views.  If you need it modified further let me know.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
    bIsClosing = True 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim wsArray() As Variant 
    Dim iCnt As Integer 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0 

    Splash.Visible = True 

    For Each wsSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
        If Not wsSht.CodeName = "Splash" Then 
            If wsSht.Visible = True Then 
                iCnt = iCnt + 1: Redim Preserve wsArray(1 To iCnt) 
                wsArray(iCnt) = wsSht.Name 
            End If 
            wsSht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 
        End If 
    Next 

    Application.EnableEvents = 0 
    ThisWorkbook.Save 
    Application.EnableEvents = 1 

    If Not bIsClosing Then 
        For iCnt = 1 To UBound(wsArray) 
            Worksheets(wsArray(iCnt)).Visible = True 
        Next iCnt 
        Splash.Visible = False 
        Cancel = True 
    End If 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Dim wsSht As Worksheet 

    For Each wsSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
        wsSht.Visible = xlSheetVisible 
    Next wsSht 

    Splash.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 

    bIsClosing = False 
End Sub
```

A sample file can be found [here.](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=89037&highlight=enable%20macros)

Comment: @Aaron, did this help, do you require more assistance?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not in a position where I can download a sample file to check, although I can follow your code snippet. This is a good answer, but I don't think it's the best answer that's been presented. I already have it set up where the user will be unlikely to switch to the "Info" screen once macros are enabled, thus hiding and unhiding worksheets at every save seems less elegant than simply switching to "Info" before each save, as has been presented in the other questions. But, this is a good solution.

Comment: @Aaron, the closing_check boolean can get out of sink if the user cancels the close, try it and you will see it is a false positive.  Also beware of auto-saves, auto recover.  Finally, I don't advice using the scheduler/on-time like you have chosen.  It should be properly cancelled within excel IMHO, it only leads to hassles from experience.  Hope that doesn't sound like sour grapes cause you didn't choose my answer, I really don't mind.  Just trying too help.  All the best.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a 'proxy workbook'.

The 'proxy workbook'

- is the only workbook which is directly opened by the users
- contains the info sheet
- contains VBA to open your 'real workbook' using Workbooks.Open (As I've checked with Workbooks.Open documentation by default it will not add the file name to your recent files history unless you set the AddToMru argument to true)
- if required the VBA code could even make sure that your 'target workbook' is trusted (I found some sample code [here](http://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=3062))

The 'target workbook'

- contains your Schedule and any other sheets
- is only opened if the VBA code in 'proxy workbook' was executed
- can be saved by the user at any time as usual

I've got no Office 2007 at hand to test this but think it should do.

Comment: this is also a solution, but I don't think the best one that's been presented since it adds another workbook that users will need to access.