# How to improve workflow on Excel beforeClose() event hiding all sheets as xlVeryHidden?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a heavily VBA based workbook where I am going to be making all sheets other than a "Make sure to enable macros" worksheet xlVeryHidden on close. I will then add code in the `Workbook_Open()` event to unhide them.

This is to prevent all modification of any objects from happening without proper events triggering, etc.

Here is the code I'm using (note there is a mirrored "on open" type event to unhide them):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    hideAllContentOnWorkbookClose

End Sub

Private Sub hideAllContentOnWorkbookClose()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Worksheets 'note: this function ensures I only do this to the right worksheets, not relevant code here
        If checkIfWorksheetShouldBeHidden(sh.CodeName) Then sh.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Next sh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However this presents an awkward situation. Because this event fires on the `Close` event, it modifies the workbook, which then triggers a "Do you want to save?" prompt.

Unfortunately, if the user presses "no" then the workbook will close with the sheets remaining unhidden. If the workbook is then opened with macros disabled, the sheets will be unhidden. Note this problem only exists if the user saves the workbook after it is opened.

I am hoping for a better alternative than simply forcing a silent save in the `BeforeClose` method. I conceivably could also intercept the "on save" and "on save as" events too and cancel them, requiring the user to save using buttons I could add (I could add "Save" and "Close" as buttons in the workbook and disable the built-in save/close events).

I'm not really a fan of either path. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing that this question is very related to your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19099252/1316573

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the concept and even some of the code mercilessly from [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13087/joe)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146233/1316573)

Something like this would fit the bill, in your workbook code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim curSheet As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set curSheet = Me.activeSheet      
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nameOfSheetYouWantToDisplay")
    If Not curSheet Is targetSheet Then
        If Module1.PreviousSheet Is Nothing Then
            Set Module1.PreviousSheet = curSheet
        End If
        targetSheet.Activate
    End If
    hideAllContentOnWorkbookClose
    Application.OnTime Now, "ActivatePreviousSheet"
End Sub
```

Then in your Module:

```
Public Sub ActivatePreviousSheet()
    If Not PreviousSheet Is Nothing Then
        PreviousSheet.Activate
        Set PreviousSheet = Nothing
    End If
    MethodCallTODisplaySheets()
    'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    '    ws.Visible = True
    'Next
End Sub
```

Just as an FYI, an alternate version for your hideAllSheets method could be this which I like due to it not depending on `checkIfWorksheetShouldBeHidden`:

```
Sub HideAllSheetsExcept(visibleSheet as Worksheet)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not ws Is visibleSheet Then
            ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

which could be called like `HideAllSheetsExcept targetSheet` in the previous code sample.

Comment: + 1 For your honesty :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am hoping for a better alternative than simply forcing a silent save in the BeforeClose method.

I don't see any problem with `Silent Save`. BTW instead of `Workbook_BeforeClose` event you can use `hideAllContentOnWorkbookClose()` instead. Not that it matters.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    hideAllContentOnWorkbookClose
    'ThisWorkbook.Saved = True 'Additional Precaution?
End Sub

Private Sub hideAllContentOnWorkbookClose()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '

    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```